# Changing user in a php program using apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, web, server

I'm developping a web site using php. This website is running with a server Apache

My goal is to be able to control the people that can upload a file. They can only upload a file if they belong to a specific group in Apache (linux group). The problem is that when someone upload a file, its not there user that upload the file its apache because they are not connected to the server, so when someone uploads a file the owner of the file its apache so I cant change the owner or the group of this file

I thought, to resolve this problem I'm going to use the command "su - user", to change the user and when I create the file, the owner it would be me not apache. But the problem its that when I use this commande, it call the pompt window to write the code but i'm using php so it wouldnt work

I have found this bash to run it in my php program but the only problem its that it doesnt work. So if you have any ideas I would be really greatfull with your help

```
> spawn su user_name
expect "Password:" { send "my_password\r" }
expect "$ " { send "/bin/sh my_script_bash\r" }
expect "$ " { exit }
```

***Important note:*** I dont have access to the user root and its password, because I'm working in a big company and I dont have the right to know some passwords

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the importance of needing the files to be written on the server as a user that is actually on the server and your approach is not something that would be considered safe or even possible at a big company.

A typical PHP application handles the authorization to allow someone to upload a file itself and would always write the files as the apache user (www) and never as a user already defined on the server.

Generally how a PHP application would solve this is to have some kind of user in the database that is authorized for uploading files to a directory on the server.
How you hook the user to the file is up to you, one approach would be to store the details of the file in the database with the user id so you know that the file belongs to the user or you could create a directory with the id or name of the user.